# Ruby on rails access Devise.sign_in_after_reset_password in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Im overriding Devise's `Devise::PasswordsController`, so i can use it as a RESTful web service. For that, i've overridden all four methods (`new`, `create`, `edit` and `update`), based in devise's original [`Devise::PasswordsController` class](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb). It's been straight forward except for the `update` method, which uses a devise attribute called `Devise.sign_in_after_reset_password`. I've found that it is defined in the [library module](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb), but when I try to access it, i get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Api::V1::PasswordsController#update

undefined method `sign_in_after_reset_password' for Devise:Module

Extracted source (around line #37):
36    resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
37    if Devise.sign_in_after_reset_password
38      flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
39      set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_flashing_format?
40      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
```

So far, I tried to `require 'devise'`, but it didn't work. I googled it for a while, but didn't find anything either. Im kind of new to ruby and to ruby on rails, so I don't really know where to look. Any help would be very appreciated. Im using `RoR 4.2.1` and `Ruby 2.2.1 (2015-02-26)`

Answer (score 4):

Check version of devise gem you use. I suppose you use the last released version (at this moment 3.4.1.) but overriding code from master.

As you can see here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.4.1/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb `Devise::PasswordsController` doesn't use `sign_in_after_reset_password` in currently released version.

`sign_in_after_reset_password` method has been introduced by the following commit: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/f0992e4a96352dbb2dfec731f46a51f99a013b29